# Finding a point on a line that intercepts the xz plane

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

[image]

I have two conceptual questions pertaining to (iii) and (iv)

(iii): I can find the angle between the line ($v-u$ in the equation $r = a + t(v-u)$ I hope?) and the xz-plane by using the dot product formula (for instance) with |$v - u$| and |$0, 1, 0$|. Why though, do I assume it to be $|0, 1, 0|$ and not $[0, y, 0]$? Why is it 1 in this case? How can it not be any y? My thought of that made this question hard to answer, because I didn't know what y to use.

(iv): For this question, my queries are as follows:

- What conditions are necessary here? Am I looking for a point on the line $r = P + t(v-u)$ such that $r$ has a $y$ value of 1?
- If the above is false (which it may well be), what conditions actually *are* necessary here, and how do I go about finding it?

Comment: So long as $y=0$ then $x$ and $z$ can be anything, and we are on the $xz$ plane.

Comment: Also reconsider your equation for the line $v-u$ is not necessarily a direction vector for the line you want. Can you think of a vector perpendicular to both $u$ and $v$?

Answer (score 0):

For (iii), hopefully you can convince yourself that the angle between a line and another line doesn't change if you extend the length of either line. So the angle between (0,1,0) and your other line doesn't change even if we change it to say, (0,1000000,0) or (0,y,0). But (0,1,0) could be chosen for easy calculation, since it is the unit normal vector to the xz-plane and therefore has magnitude 1. Take a look at this diagram that I stole off of a tutoring website for more detail:

[image: http://www.vitutor.us/geometry/distance/images/24.gif]

By doing the dot product you can find the angle β between the normal vector and the line *r*.

For (iv), your line *r* that you found should intersect the xz-plane when its y value = 0 (not 1). If it were 1, then you would be 1 unit of y above the xz-plane, not intersecting.